# Is there a good way (PHP class) to acces Gmail Contacs?

Tags: php, gmail, contact-list

Is there a good way (PHP class/function) to access Gmail Contacts List? If not where I can start to build a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[OpenInviter](http://openinviter.com/)**, it's open source and works with Gmail and many more.

Answer (score 2):

I know [**libgmailer** (class GMailer)](http://gmail-lite.sourceforge.net/wordpress/index.php/about/libgmailer/) (requires CURL and OpenSSL).

> **Mail management:** read, compose, save
>   draft, send, apply labels, remove
>   labels, apply star, remove star,
>   download attachment, search, etc.
>
> **Account management:** edit filters, edit
>   contact list, edit label list, edit
>   Gmail perferences, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try with Zend Framework's Zend_GData http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html? And here's an example: http://blog.charlvn.com/2008/11/google-contacts-api-with-zend-framework.html how to use it.